# How to obtain field values from a sitecore droplist used as a predefined list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

In my template I have a field type of Droplist which maps to a Sitecore folder holding values for the Droplist which in this case is Colours. This is so that an editor cannot make a typo or invent a colour this is not in the pre-defined list.

So that colour is based off a template I call TAGS which has a single field type of 'colour' and here I create a series of items using that template to create the colours for the swatch list.

When I access the main template I duly see the colour values in that Droplist so its working as I would expect it because I can access that fields values:

```cs
tileValues.Attributes["class"] += " tile-" + Item.Fields["Tile Colour"].Value.ToLower();
```

However I have realized its not using the field value of the template but rather the name I have called the item. SO its just a happy mistake that its achieving the result I wanted.

However how would I obtain the actual field value for that item in the end code. I have scenarios where there will be multi lingual editors so we may name the tags as rouge, blanc etc which is what the editor will see on selection in the Droplist but we need the colour value of the field to still say red or white etc

I tried:

```cs
Item.Fields["Tile Colour"].Item.Fields["Colour"].Value
```

But this failed despite the API hint implying its valid.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me obtain the actual field value and not the items name.

Comment: You can use droplink instead of droplist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Sitecore Climber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4616839/sitecore-climber) wrote, don't use `Droplist` field type - it stores item name only and you cannot get the item itself in the code behind.

Use `Droplink` field type - it stores ID of the item.

Then you can get the item:

```cs
Item colourItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Item["Tile Colour"]);
if (colourItem != null)
{
    string colour = colourItem["Colour"];
|
```

Comment: Thanks again Marek - I've swapped out the field type to droplink and reset the values on the items - using your above code I receive error - Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. In relation to line
string colour = colourItem["Colour"];

Colour is set and published on the templates within the folder that the droplink points to.

Comment: Are the colour items themselves published?

Comment: If you have used my code, you would not get exception - there is a null check ;) You need to debug and check what is the value of `Item["Tile Colour"]` (it should be a guid), and whether item with that guid is in your web database.